# Git, how to ignore my current changes and pull from remote (as fresh clone of remote)

Tags: git

I have git-setup with a remote 'origin' repository, and local repositories on my work desktop and laptop.

Now I did some work on my laptop last night, and pushed it to the remote.

Now I want to ignore / overwrite the changes I made on my desktop, and pull the remote 'origin' down as fresh copy - like when you first clone a repository.

Comment: I had a feeling someone would have asked the same thing, but didn't find it in my search.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for Charles, thanks. How do I close the question now, or accept the answer from the other question?

Comment: You can't accept the answer of other question, because it's already accepted, but you can upvote it (both question and answer). Your question will get closed when 3 more people will vote for closing

Answer (score 0):

The following command will reset your current working directory to the last commit. Be warned though as it will remove all your local changes.

```
git checkout -- .
git pull
```

I can really recommend reading the pro git book as it covers all the basics of git really well.

http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: This won't pull from the remote, as requested in the question

Comment: It is still complaining about files that need merged. Something (my IDE?) has created a __pycache__ folder and it is the files in there that "need merged".

Comment: That sounds more like you are inside of a merge. What does the output of git status give you?

Comment: Added a git pull statement after the checkout to do the requested pull.